# FloatingActionButton ,como aparecer em todas as telas?

Tags: android

Como faço com que esse FloatingActionButton (Botão do email) apareça em todas as minhas telas , sem precisar ter que ficar colocando uma em cada tela?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se são `activities` diferentes, tu precisa colocar ele em todas elas.

Comment: se voce criou ele a partir do menu normal de criar app do android studio, esse floatactinobutton é parte de uma activity que usa fragments, dai basta que voce implement varios fragments usando sempre a activity main e trabalha nesses fragments para serem exibido nela, fica mais facil de lidar, assim

Answer (score 2):

O **FloatingActionButton** esta inserido na Activity criada. Para ter esse efeito que você deseja o aconselhável você trabalhar trocando o miolo da tela através de **Fragments**. Com isso o botão sempre será visível para todas as telas pois estará presente na activity enquanto os fragments são trocados. No caso que você precise criar outra Activity é necessário inserir um novo **FloatingActionButton**.

**Exemplo de como trabalhar com fragments:**
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer